# How to forward response headers through GraphQL to client

Tags: node.js, graphql, passport.js

I'm having an issue using GraphQL where the response headers are being dropped when returning to client. My application is using NodeJS, Passport.js and Express Cookie-Session to manage authentication and sessions.

I have an existing `/login` route which authenticates with Passport and returns a `user{}` object and `set-cookie` headers to the client. In result, a cookie is created on the client's browser and their session is established.

Now, we have recently added GraphQL and I created a `login` query, which calls the existing `/login` route and responds with the `user{}` object. However, when the GraphQL returns the response to the client, the response headers are no longer included so the cookie is never created.

How can I forward the original response headers through GraphQL to reach the client?

Here is an example of the GraphQL login:

```
login { 
  type: typeLogin,
  args : { 'username/password here' },
  async resolve(_, args, context) {
    const response = await fetch('/login', {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify('username/password here')
   })

   const data = await response.json();

   // console.log(response.headers) will display correct headers

   return data; // User is returned but response headers are not
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I already do that,

Link: https://github.com/masmerino13/graphql-backend/blob/master/src/resolvers/Mutations/UserMutation.js#L31

Let me know if this works for you

Regards!

Comment: Thank you this is helpful to show how to create a cookie within the GraphQL response. However, in my case the cookie is created within the Node endpoint and needs to be forwarded through GraphQL to the client. GraphQL is basically a middleman forwarding the cookie along to the user.

Comment: Yes, have you tested something like this?

`context.res.set('cookie', cookieValue);`

Ref: https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/71